# Edits needed to allow mixed-case url titles?

Tags: url-title

I know hacking the EE source is discouraged, but since there is no option for preserving title case in urls (that is, not reverting everything to lower case), it is something I've been stuck doing for years. I had some initial help figuring out where I needed to make changes, but that was on EE 1.x and I am a bit concerned that I am actually editing more than I need to edit now that I am on 2.x.

What I do is the following:

In system/expressionengine/modules/channel/libaries/channel_form/Channel_form_lib.php

```
I comment out NewText = NewText.toLowerCase();

I also add “A-Z” to NewText = NewText.replace(/[^a-z0-9-_]/g,'');
```

In system/expressionengine/helpers/EE_url_helper.php

```
I remove strtolower() from this section

        if ($lowercase === TRUE)
        {
            $str = strtolower($str);    
        }

I also add "A-Z" to [^a-z0-9\-\._]
```

In themes/javascript/compressed/jquery/plugins/ee_url_title.js

```
I remove .toLowerCase() and I add A-Z to [^a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]
```

Am I in fact editing some sections that don't need to be edited in order to preserve url titles with the same case as titles? Less editing for each update would of course be welcome.

Comment: I can't offer answer but I'd be interested to know the reasons why you need to do this - which actually may lead to a different, simpler solution for you.

Comment: There's a couple of reasons. One is that the site is now quite well established and it would lead to a lot of link issues if I were to change. The other, which is why I did it in the first place, is that I prefer it visually. The site is divided into several subsections via directories and those use mixed-caps for clarity (such as "GoT" or "ASoIaF". It always seemed very odd to me to have all lower-case on titles together with that.

Comment: Personal preference aside, a perfectly valid reason. What "link issues" would it lead to? Apache, unlike IIS, is case-insensitive unless you take steps to make it otherwise by modifying Apache's config. So "/got-page" is the same as "/GoT-Page". Likewise from a Search Engine perspective, the two are the same. So really it is just a style thing. I'd say modding the core of EE and the risks involved is less desirable than manually editing the URLs when you create some content. Also from user's perspective - I feel all lowercase URLs are easier to use/remember. Each to their own though! :)

Comment: But now I see you're running on Nginx :)

Comment: Yes, we used to be on Apache and then it was less of an issue both in terms of people misremembering what case to use and with potential link issues. If I had started the site up today I would probably have gone all lowercase (even if I do dislike how it looks, especially with urls that include names), but now it would be a difficult transition.